# What is the value that captured into BYPASS register?

Tags: jtag

The IEEE1149.1 describes many cases of capturing some value in the CAPTURE_IR/CAPTURE_DR stages to the internal registers. For example, the instruction register shall be filled with "...XXXX01" (the exact value is defined by the INSTRUCTION_CAPTURE atribute of the BSDL file) value in the CAPTURE_DR stage. The REGISTER_ACCESS atribute is also may describe such value (for a custom register) by string:

```
"MY_REG[8](MY_INSTRUCTION CAPTURES 01010101)," &
```

But I can't find what is the value (0 or 1) that captured into the BYPASS register in the CAPTURE_DR stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bypass register capture value is defined as "0".

See IEEE-Std-1149.1-2001, chapter 10.1.1, rule b:

> When the bypass register is selected for inclusion in the serial path between TDI and TDO by the current instruction, the shift-register stage shall be set to a logic zero on the rising edge of TCK after entry into the Capture-DR controller state.